# Display parent-child relation yii2

Tags: view, parent-child, relationship, yii2, relation

I am looking for some way to implement the following thing with yii2:

Lets imagine we have the following structure:
- authors table.
- Books table

Each author -> has written 1 or more books.

What I want to do is to display on a view, the details of an author, and under it, a gridview of all the books it has written. After that, control buttons to create/ remove new books for that current author, along with a gridview of the books which belongs to the current author... In some other words, a master-detail view.

How I should retrieve the data of the books? From the same controller for Authors?

I have already implemented the table relations between authors and books, in the Author's model

Thanks in advance, any help is welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

If the you have the following relation in your Author model:

```
public function getBooks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Books::className(), ['author_id' => 'id']);
}
```

After declaring relations, getting relational data is as easy as accessing a component property that is defined by the corresponding getter method:

```
$author = Author::findOne(1);
$books = $author->books;
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found at the end was to :

- On the Author's controller, I modified the "view" action, so I could a "books" activeDataprovider, and then filtering it by "author id":

  public function actionView($id)
      {
          //get current author 
           $author=$this->findModel($id);

  ```
      $books_search = new BookSearch();

      //get the related books for current author

   $written_books =  $books_search->search(['bookSearch'=>['id_author'=>$id]]);
          return $this->render('view', [
          'author' => $author,
          'books_search'=> $books_search,
          'books'=>$written_books,
      ]);
  }
  ```

Then I could create on the Author's view, a gridview with the books written by the current author